# How to display Java ArrayList values as Comma separated values

Tags: java, arraylist, output

I have a scenario where I need to fetch 500 from web service api and display the final output values as comma separated values like id,name,owner,account,path,ccvalues. To achieve this I am writing a method where Iam getting all this information and setting to one java object. Fields are below. Finally i created one list which holds this Video objects. videos.add(video)

```
String identifier;
String name;
String ownerName;
String accountName;
String mediaPath;
List<KalturaLanguage> ccList;
```

Now how to display my output from videos list object. Please help me resolving this.

code is:

```
for (String mediaId : mediaList) {
                    if (mediaId != null) {
                        String mediaFullPath = getMediaPath(mediaId);
                        entryInfo = getMedia(mediaId);
                        metadataList = getMetadata(mediaId);
                        ccs = getClosedCaptions(mediaId);
                        if (entryInfo != null) {
                            video = new Video();
                            System.out.println("entryInfo.id"
                                    + entryInfo.id);
                            System.out.println("entryInfo.name"
                                    + entryInfo.name);
                            System.out.println("mediaFullPath"
                                    + mediaFullPath);
                            video.setIdentifier(entryInfo.id);
                            video.setName(entryInfo.name);
                            video.setMediaPath(mediaFullPath);
                        }

                        if (metadataList != null
                                && metadataList.totalCount != 0) {
                            List<KalturaMetadata> metadataObjs = metadataList.objects;
                            if (metadataObjs != null
                                    && metadataObjs.size() > 0) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < metadataObjs.size(); i++) {
                                    KalturaMetadata metadata = metadataObjs
                                            .get(i);
                                    if (metadata != null) {
                                        if (metadata.xml != null) {
                                            metadataValues = parseXml(metadata.xml);
                                            if (metadataValues.size() != 0) {
                                                ibmAccountList = metadataValues
                                                        .get(0);
                                                for (String account : ibmAccountList) {
                                                    System.out
                                                            .println("IBM Account Name ------->"
                                                                    + account);
                                                    video.setAccountName(account);
                                                }
                                                ownerList = metadataValues
                                                        .get(1);
                                                for (String owner : ownerList) {
                                                    System.out
                                                            .println("Account Owner Name ------->"
                                                                    + owner);
                                                    video.setOwnerName(owner);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (ccs.size() != 0) {
                        for (Map.Entry<String, List<KalturaCaptionAsset>> entry : ccs
                                .entrySet()) {
                            String key = entry.getKey();
                            List<KalturaCaptionAsset> values = entry
                                    .getValue();
                            // System.out.println("Key = " + key);
                            for (KalturaCaptionAsset asset : values) {
                                System.out.println(" CC value : "
                                        + asset.language);
                                ccList.add(asset.language);
                                video.setCcList(ccList);
                                videos.add(video);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: need to fetch 500 what??

Comment: Are you looking for printing all Video pojo objects within the list in specific order, please elaborate your question.

Answer (score 3):

You are going in a wrong direction. Just implement your `toString` method inside `Video` class.

When you iterate over list and print video object it calls `toString` method inside the video class.

While providing implementation in video class, generate a String in required format.

Comment: I don't actually think this is a good idea. `toString` is to be used for short human-readable forms (e.g. for logging and debugging) and not as a basis for data transfer and conversion. I'd create a separate method for this (`getAsCsv()` or something like that).

Comment: Thank you. while overriding toString method, How to display all list values of List<Kalturalanguage> field.    public String toString() {
  return identifier + "," + name + "," + ownerName + "," + mediaPath
    + "," + accountName;
 }

Comment: @RealSkeptic Sorry but I strongly disagree. Implementing proper toString with valuable info is not a bad idea :)

Comment: It's not a bad idea. You should *always* do it. But you should *not* use it as the basis for anything that smells like serialization/deserialization. Separating the uses allows you to make the `toString` more concise and readable, and allows you to change it in future versions.

Comment: @RajyalakshmiS Implement toString in `KalturaLanguage` class. Then iterate here over in video class and append to the main string.

Comment: @Suresh - KalturaLanguage is a client class which is as part of web service. I cannot change that.

Comment: @RajyalakshmiS So you can build a string with the attributes that class provided right  ?

Comment: @Suresh - Yes I can do that.

Comment: @RajyalakshmiS Yah.. Please goahead.

Comment: @Suresh - The above is what i wrote. Can you please add code for appending List<KalturaLanguage> in toString.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86874/discussion-between-ss--and-rajyalakshmi-s).